# Express various trig functions in terms of the sine.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The acute angle $x$ radians is such that $\sin x = k$, where $k$ is a positive constant.
Express, in terms of $k$.

i) $\sin (2\pi-x)$

ii) $\tan(\frac{1}{2}\pi-x)$

iii) $\cos (\pi+x)$

My attempt:

$\sin (2\pi-x)=-\sin (x)=-k$

$\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi-x\right)=\cot x=\frac{1}{\frac{k}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}}$

$=\frac{\sqrt{1-k^2}}{k}$

How about (iii) ?

I've a question here. Is there a specific way to memorize these formula?

Comment: $$\cos(\pi+y)=-\cos y$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\iff \cos^2x=1-\sin^2x\iff \cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$$ Now, we have $$\cos(\pi+x)=-\cos x=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}=-\sqrt{1-k^2}$$
$$\forall\ \ 0<k\leq 1$$

Comment: Is my question ii correct?

Comment: yes that is correct for all positive values of $0<k\leq 1$